# Use PHP to extract query string from TXT file, form URI and make HTTP POST

Tags: php, string, http, post

I'd like to use PHP to look at a text file on my local machine.  On line 1 of the file, a query string is generated automatically every few minutes:

```
Example: ?artist=myartist&title=mytitle&songtype=S&duration=240000
```

I'd like to check the file every 5-10 seconds, then take the query string, append it to

```
http://localhost:9595
```

Final HTTP request should look like:

```
http://localhost:9595?artist=myartist&title=mytitle&songtype=S&duration=240000
```

I'm NOT a code writer but have taken suggestions from others and gotten close (I think).

Code below.

```
<?php
/**
* This program will check a file every 5 seconds to see if it has changed...if it has,     the new metadata will be sent to the shoutcast server(s)
*/

//the path to the file where your song information is placed...it is assumed that     everything is on one line and is in the format you wish to send to the server
DEFINE('songfile', "c:\a\nowplaying.txt");

//simply copy and paste this for each server you need to add
$serv["host"][] = "127.0.0.1";
$serv["port"][] = "9595";

while(1)
{
$t=time();
clearstatcache();
$mt=@filemtime(songfile);
if ($mt===FALSE || $mt<1)
{
    echo "file not found, will retry in 5 seconds";
    sleep(5);
    continue;
}

if ($mt==$lastmtime)
{
    //file unchanged, will retry in 5 seconds
    sleep(5);
    continue;
}

$da="";
$f=@fopen(songfile, "r");
if ($f!=0)
{
    $da=@fread($f, 4096);
    fclose($f);
    @unlink(songfile);
}
else
{
    echo "error opening songfile, will retry in 5";
    sleep(5);
    continue;
}

$lastmtime=$mt;

for($count=0; $count < count($serv["host"]); $count++)
{
    $mysession = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_URL, "http://".$serv["host"][$count].":".$serv["port"][$count]."/?mode=updinfo&song=".urlencode(trim($da)));
    curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
    curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
    curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
    curl_exec($mysession);
    curl_close($mysession);
}

echo "song updated";

sleep(5);
}
?>
```

Comment: please post your PHP code too

Comment: Something like this: `$url = 'http://localhost:9595?' .  explode(' ', $otherString)[1];`

Comment: I am using code created by someone else.  Things seem to fall apart at line 51, 52.

Comment: Just added code, after line 51 things become a mess... I feel like I'm close but I may be far off the mark. :)  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd change `songfile` to upper-case, just like the `CURLOPT` constants. This is a convention for constants, to show it is not a variable missing its dollar prefix.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

something like this....

```
$file = fopen("nowplaying.txt", 'r');
$line = fgets($file);
fclose($file);
$url = "http://localhost:9595" . $line;
urlencode(trim($url));
$mysession = curl_init();
curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6");
curl_setopt($mysession, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_exec($mysession);
curl_close($mysession);
```

As for the 5-10 second loop, I'd stay away from doing that in PHP and instead try running the script as a scheduled task or something.  Also, this code has no error checking so you may want to add some.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for yours  are as follow make a ajax call to the PHP.

Here is the `every5sec.php` file:

```
<?php 
$file = fopen("c:\a\nowplaying.txt", 'r');
$line = fgets($file);
fclose($file);
$url = "http://localhost:9595" . $line;
echo $url;
exit;
?>
```

JavaScript file here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function refresh() {
        $.get('every5sec.php', function(data){
            $.load(data);
        });
}
setTimeout(refresh, 2000); 

</script>
```

I think this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your help.

After reading (and reading a lot) and with some code help from you fine folks I was able to get this working.  I ended up using the below code and it's running great with one exception.  I get a file lock every once in awhile, more specifically an error message (Warning: fopen(nowplaying.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\b\nowplaying.php on line 22) -- it seems to only happen when the code tries to get the file while it's being updated.

Can I write an exception that (if the above error appears, the script will try again in 2 seconds?

**UPDATE**

I changed this section:

```
 $file = fopen("nowplaying.txt", 'r');
 $line = fgets($file);
 fclose($file);
 $url = "http://127.0.0.1:9696" . $line;
```

To:

```
$filename = 'nowplaying.txt';
$file = fopen($filename, 'r')
or exit("unable to open file ($filename)");
$line = fgets($file);
fclose($file);
$url = "http://127.0.0.1:9696" . $line;
```

I then put a SLEEP command at the end of the batch file I'm using to launch the code that starts it over if it exits.  So far so good. :)

My Original Code:

```
<?php

while(1)
{
$t=time();
clearstatcache();
$mt=@filemtime("nowplaying.txt");
if ($mt===FALSE || $mt<1)
{
echo "file not found, will retry in 5 seconds";
sleep(5);
continue;
}

if ($mt==$lastmtime)
{
sleep(5);
continue;
}

$file = fopen("nowplaying.txt", 'r');
$line = fgets($file);
fclose($file);
$url = "http://127.0.0.1:9696" . $line; 

$lastmtime=$mt;

$options = array(
'http' => array(
),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

var_dump($result);

sleep(5); 

}
?>
```